SSH connection will be disconnected automatically with SecureCRT on macOS
When I initiate a SSH connection by SecureCRT and there is continuous outputs within the session, wait a while and the connection will be disconnected automatically. And it reads:

"The client has disconnected from the server. Reason: Invalid packet header. This probably indicates a problem with key exchange or encryption."

SecureCRT Version: 9.5.1 (ARM64 build 3272)
Easy way to replication: Continually input the Enter. I've tried the "Terminal" app and it won't, so I think it's SecureCRT's problem. And I think it's not the timeout problem, because I've set the "Send Protocol NO-OP" option, if I don't do anything with the session, it won't disconnect for a long time.
